# Command-line argument modification - C programming

Tags: c, if-statement, command-line, arguments

```
int main(int argc, char** argc) {

.....


if(argc != 6 && int argc[1] <30 && int argc[2] <30) {
    }
}
```

Hey people, I am trying to character limit my command line arguments for main function. This will limit the 2nd and 3rd argument entered to under 30 integers in length. The error i am receiving is "error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer". In C, is this how I access the index value of each arg, argc0, argc[1] (second arguement) etc. 
any clarification would be great! thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "under 30 integers in length"? as in 30 characters in the string argument?

Comment: the argument must be below 30 things, ie. cells, or rows, columns etc.

Comment: also, why do you have the `int` keyword before your references to `argc`? you should only need to specify type when declaring or casting

Answer (score 4):

Change
`if(argc != 6 && int argc[1] <30 && int argc[2] <30)`
to
 `if(argc != 6 && strlen (argv[1]) <30 && strlen (argv[2]) <30)`

char* argv[] is about parameters.

Comment: You're missing `(` in your `strlen` call

Comment: my apologies, <30 is the parameter of the argument. So argv[1] needs to be less than 30. Is this making the string input of the command-line input <30?

Comment: Then you need atoi() function. This will make your parameter an integer so that you can check if it is less than 30.

Comment: And the spec has moved! Don't you just hate that? +1 for answering the original question correctly.

Comment: @Bathsheba I've removed the extra parentheses a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //...
    if(argc != 6 && strlen(argv[1]) < 30 && strlen(argv[2]) < 30)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Firstly, you have both of your parameters named `argc`, that's not right, but ill assume thats just a typo.

Second, `argv` is a pointer to a string (which is itself a pointer to a char). That means that you cannot compare its value to an integer without some other function call or cast. in this case I assume you mean that you want to limit your argumetns to 30 characters in length.

If you do not want to limit your arguments based on their length but their value you need to use a function call to get the value in the string.

For instance, if you want to limit arguments based on the numerical value of your argument then replace `strlen` with `atoi` but then be aware that if a user enters non numeric input you will get strange values.

Comment: You should change argc[1] to argv[1].

Comment: my apologies, <30 is the parameter of the argument. So argc[1] needs to be less than 30,etc.. Is this making the string input of the command-line input <30?

Comment: @Sam23yo argv[1] is always a string, am i correct in understanding that the string you expect is a set of numbers like "23"? and you want that numerical value to be less than 30?